# How to create a header file for my existing C program in linux to connect with MySql?

Tags: c, linux, cgi, header-files

it's my first time I use Linux and C programming. I've wrote a file in **C language to connect with MySQL** and it's working fine now. Now I've to integrate this file into my company **web-based system which is written with CGI ( C )**. So I guess I should make my file as a header file and call this file from the CGI. **How should I create a header file** ? Or is there any better way ? I google on the net but not so lucky with CGI. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Update question to how to create a dynamic library. Or create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that putting everything in a header file is the best solution.

- Create a header file and put the
  function prototypes and structure
  declarations in it
- Create a C file and put function definitions in it

Then you can either link with the object file obtained or you can create a dynamic library.